# stdout to a file , stderr to a command

Tags: unix, stdout, stderr

How should I do it?

Let's say I use `ls / /NotExisting` And I want the result of `/` to go to a file `results.txt` and the `/NotExisting` ( assuming this is an error ) to go to a command `cksum`

I can do that separately like `ls / /NotExisting > results.txt`

and `ls / /NotExisting 2> >(cksum)` which gives me something similar of what I want to achieve, but not quite there yet.  So how do I join these two lines together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls / /NotExisting 2>&1 >results.txt | cksum
```

You know how if you want to send both stdout and stderr to a file, you need to write
`somecommand >file 2>&1` and the other order doesn't work? Well the way that it "doesn't work" is exactly what you want for this example.

*First*, this command redirects stderr to where stdout is currently going (which will be the input of the pipe to `cksum`), *then* it redirects stdout to `results.txt` (which will not affect stderr).